TypeScript: Nested Mapping Results in "never" Type Instead of Expected Object Type
I’m working on a TypeScript function that maps an input object (payload) to a specified structure defined by a DataMapping. The mapping can involve simple fields, nested objects, and validation. However, I’m running into an issue where the expected nested object type is being inferred as never in the result.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
type SimpleFieldOptions = {
  inputKey?: string;
  validators?: Array<(value: any) => boolean>;
};

type NestedFieldOptions<M> = {
  nested: FieldMapping<M>;
};

type FieldMapping<M> = {
  [K in keyof M]: SimpleFieldOptions | NestedFieldOptions<M[K]> | true;
};

type DataMapping<M> = {
  fields: FieldMapping<M>;
};

type MapResult<M, F extends DataMapping<M>> = {
  [K in keyof F['fields']]: F['fields'][K] extends SimpleFieldOptions
    ? M[K]
    : F['fields'][K] extends NestedFieldOptions<infer N>
    ? MapResult<N, DataMapping<N>>
    : F['fields'][K] extends true
    ? M[K]
    : never;
};

function mapData<M, F extends DataMapping<M>>(payload: Record<string, any>, mapping: F): MapResult<M, F> {
  const result = {} as MapResult<M, F>;

  for (const key in mapping.fields) {
    const fieldConfig = mapping.fields[key];
    const typedKey = key as keyof MapResult<M, F>;

    if (fieldConfig === true) {
      result[typedKey] = payload[key] as M[typeof typedKey];
    } else if (isSimpleFieldOptions(fieldConfig)) {
      const value = payload[fieldConfig.inputKey || key];

      if (fieldConfig.validators) {
        for (const validator of fieldConfig.validators) {
          if (!validator(value)) {
            throw new Error(`Validation failed for key: ${String(typedKey)} with value: ${value}`);
          }
        }
      }
      result[typedKey] = value as M[typeof typedKey];
    } else if (isNestedFieldOptions(fieldConfig)) {
      result[typedKey] = mapData(payload, { fields: fieldConfig.nested }) as any;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

function isSimpleFieldOptions(option: any): option is SimpleFieldOptions {
  return option && typeof option === 'object' && ('inputKey' in option || 'validators' in option);
}

function isNestedFieldOptions<T>(option: any): option is NestedFieldOptions<T> {
  return option && typeof option === 'object' && option.nested && typeof option.nested === 'object';
}

class Address {
  street!: string;
  city!: string;
  zipCode!: string;
}

class Building {
  name!: string;
  description!: string;
  address!: Address;
}

class Apartment {
  apartmentId!: string;
  buildingId!: string;
  building!: Building;
}

const apartmentMapping: DataMapping<Apartment> = {
  fields: {
    apartmentId: true,
    buildingId: true,
    building: {
      nested: {
        name: { inputKey: 'buildingName', validators: [(value) => typeof value === 'string'] },
        description: { inputKey: 'buildingDescription', validators: [(value) => typeof value === 'string'] },
        address: {
          nested: {
            street: { inputKey: 'streetName', validators: [(value) => typeof value === 'string'] },
            city: { inputKey: 'cityName', validators: [(value) => typeof value === 'string'] },
            zipCode: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const payload = {
  apartmentId: '321-cba',
  buildingId: '123-abc',
  buildingName: 'Sunrise Apartments',
  buildingDescription: 'A modern apartment complex.',
  streetName: 'Sunset Boulevard',
  cityName: 'Los Angeles',
  zipCode: '90001',
};

const processedResult = mapData(payload, apartmentMapping);

// Type of processedResult.building is 'never', but I expect it to be of type 'Building'

The building key in processedResult is inferred as never instead of the expected Building type. I believe the issue might be related to how I'm handling the nested mapping or the MapResult type definition, but I'm not sure how to fix it. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] without issues unrelated to the question. Right now there are lots of error you're not asking about (mostly bad generic indexes) and it makes it hard to wade through it to see what's going on. Also, there are over a hundred lines of code here; it might be simpler than your actual code, but it's longer than a minimal example should be. If you're asking about types, you can probably remove all the implementation and just use declare. I can make the code look like this, for example (but you need to fix those M things).

(see prev comment). I'm not sure how, in principle, you expect to divine the type of M[K] from a value of type SimpleFieldOptions or true. Imagine I call mapData(payload, { fields: { a: {}, b: true } }) (assuming that first argument is unhelpful because it's Record<string, any>.) What is the expected type of a and b there? If you can figure out how to fully encode M into DataMapping<M> then there's some way to do this, otherwise it's always going to be ‍♂️. So you should probably also [edit] to explain what that means. Is it always string?
